# What is the most efficient algorithm for finding the highest average in an array if we have cake with pieces?

Tags: java

- We are trying to find out which piece in the cake is the highest average.
- The cake has numbers [ 1, 3, 4, 2, 2 ]
- Piece [3, 4] results in the average 3.5
- The slice that results in the highest average is our answer

Comment: Does the array always contain positive numbers?

Comment: just remove everything but the largest number

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - I think you can only remove one slice

Comment: @StephenC not specified... and a cake can be round - still only one slice

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, I agree with your solution ... it will work only if the ends are assumed to be adjacent to each other

Comment: as @CarlosHeuberger has already pointed out, the problem as given has a trivial solution.  Please post *all* of the problem specifications.

Comment: @Prune even if "slice" is just one contiguous subarray?

Comment: Yes -- see @CarlosHeuberger's comments.

Comment: @Prune how can we "remove everything but the largest number" if we're allowed to remove just one contiguous subarray and the input is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 455, 3, 2, 1]` ?

Comment: Slice size 7, index 5.

Comment: @Prune oh you're assuming wrap-around, ok. Cakes can also be rectangular :)

Comment: Yes, which is a premise of the comments I cited in my first comment.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - Well yea.  But let's assume that this isn't a "trick" question.

Comment: Hi guys! @CarlosHeuberger solution was really close, unfortunately the slice cannot wrap around the ends of the cake, otherwise  I could just say that and my interview would be over in a second!

Comment: @גלעדברקן has shown in the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 455, 3, 2, 1] that the highest average 455 cannot be reached because we cant isolate the highest number, however if we slice at index 0 with a size 4 slice, we get our highest average of 115.25

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly do this in O(N) time.  I would like to say that I figured this out in a short enough time for a job interview, but I think that would be a lie.

The trick is this:  You only need to consider slices that start at either end.

Proof:  If you are left with a remainder that consists of two pieces, the average value in the remainder will be between the average values in the two pieces.  If you throw away the piece with the lower average value, then the overall average will go up.  If both pieces have the same average, then you can throw away either one and the overall average will not change.

```
static int[] getBestSlice(int[] cake)
{
    if (cake == null || cake.length < 1)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("THE CAKE IS A LIE!");
    }
    long leftSum = cake[0];
    long rightSum = cake[cake.length-1];
    long bestLeftSum = leftSum;
    long bestRightSum = rightSum;
    int bestLeftLen=1;
    int bestRightLen=1;
    for (int len=2; len<=cake.length; ++len)
    {
        leftSum += cake[len-1];
        rightSum += cake[cake.length-len];
        // a/b > c/d <=> ad > cb
        if (leftSum*bestLeftLen > bestLeftSum*len)
        {
            bestLeftSum = leftSum;
            bestLeftLen = len;
        }
        if (rightSum*bestRightLen > bestRightSum*len)
        {
            bestRightSum = rightSum;
            bestRightLen = len;
        }
    }
    if (bestLeftSum*bestRightLen > bestRightSum*bestLeftLen)
    {
        //best remainder is on the left -- slice off the right
        return new int[]{bestLeftLen, cake.length-bestLeftLen};
    }
    else
    {
        //best remainder is on the right -- slice off the left
        return new int[]{0,cake.length-bestRightLen};
    }
}
```